# Sending different data forms/types through TCP in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

```py
import socket
s = socket.socket()

port = 12345

s.connect(("127.0.0.1, port))

a = "Hii"

b = 25

c = b'\xAA\xEE'

s.send(a,b,c)

s.close()
```

Question 1. Is there a way that I can send all three a,b,c at the same time, rather than sending 3 times.

Question 2. If all 3 are in bytes then, is there a way I can concatenate them and send?

Comment: You will need some sort of encoding. You could try json.

Comment: @quamrana Can you please tell me if the encoding is for my question 1 or question 2

Comment: `json` is more suitable for strings and numbers. You create a list of items, encode to a single `json` string and send that string.